# converting Object -HashMap to XMLObject

Tags: java, web-services, xml-serialization, apache-axis, xmlbeans

I have created a webservice which takes a HashMap as parameter.
I generated the stubs/skeletion using XMLBeans and I am trying to set the values in the parameter and pass it to the webservice.

The issue is:
I have the HashMap or List and API is expecting it to be XMLObject is there any conversion utility which can be useful to convert my value to XMLObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure about conversion, but I have successfully sent HashMap via webservice by wrapping the HashMap in an object like so:

```
class MapObject {
    HashMap<String, String> myMap;

    public MapObject(){}

    public HashMap<String, String> getMap() {
        return myMap;
    }

    public void setMyMap(HashMap<String, String> myMap) {
        this.myMap = myMap;
    }
}
```

Then just make your web service parameter type MapObject.